# Grails 2.3.7 database tables doesn't contain foreign key

Tags: grails

I have 2 domain classes User and Company

```
class User {

   String name
   String surname

   static belongsTo = [ company : Company ]

   static constraints = {
       company nullable: true
   }
}
```

And

```
class Company {

   String name
   User createdBy

   static hasOne = [ user : User ]

   static constraints = {
   }
}
```

Notice the static belongsTo = [ company : Company ] and static hasOne = [ user : User ]

However when I view my database neither table User nor Company has any foreign key, and there is only the two tables, so no COMPANY_USER or USER_COMPANY, see screenshot

[image]

[image]

When I change hasOne to hasMany I get the expected behavior.

Comment: In hasOne relation, the primary key will be shared by both. In your case user.id will be same company.id

Comment: You Sir, are wrong, add this to bootstrap to test.  User otherUser = new User(name:'otherName',surname: 'otherSurname').save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
        User companyUser = new User(name:'companyUser',surname: 'companySurname').save(flush: true, failOnError: true)

        Company company1 = new Company(name: 'companyName', user:companyUser).save(flush: true, failOnError: true)
        Company company2 = new Company(name: 'otherName', user:otherUser).save(flush: true, failOnError: true)